# Find the values of a and b such that the limit = 8

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

[image: Please click here to view the question]

Hey so our professor always enjoys giving us these brain teasers at the end of each lecture, we usually tend to solve them but this one managed to confuse us all, correct me if I'm wrong I just started diving into calculus but using the theorems that we studied in limits the only approach I could think of is by using the conjugate method to somehow make the $a-cos(bx)$ to $sin$ but I believe my approach is way off, since ***a*** could be any number

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: This is really not a brain teaser. What would happen if $a=10$? Since the limit must converge but the denominator goes to zero, what must you do to the numerator? Work it through. You need to use your pencil as much as your brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then value of 'a' has to be one or the limit would not be 0/0 and hence not exist then you can use normal procedure

Another way of going about problems of this model is writing Taylor expansions and making and making all the coefficients of terms in numerator of power less than denominator zero

Good luck for Jee if that's wt its for